# How to remove entries PHP array and also remove those entries from other arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to remove duplicate entries in a PHP array by using array_unique. However I have 3 three different arrays: names, emails and websites.

```
Names

Array
(
    [0] => Blabla Company
    [1] => Lawyer
    [2] => Plumber
    [3] => Plumber
)

Websites

Array
(
    [0] => Blabla.com
    [1] => Lawyer.com
    [2] => Plumber.com
    [3] => 
)

Emails

Array
(
    [0] => info@Blabla.com
    [1] => info@Lawyer.com
    [2] => info@Plumber.com
    [3] => info@Plumber.com
)
```

What I want to do is let array_unique take the email array to remove duplicate entries. However the entries that it will delete also have to be deleted in the other arrays. So in this example in the email array the array_unique function will delete [3]. I then want to delete [3] in the website and names arrays, but I have no clue on how to do this...

The reason I want to do this is because I will be using the arrays as input for a SQL insert query. Otherwise the arrays don't match up anymore and the sql database will be useless.

Comment: why have you 3 arrays with identical key-indexes? cleaner way could be to have one array eg array[0]=>array('name'=>'Blabal','website'=>'blabl.com','emails'=>'info@blabla.com'), ...

Comment: Use the email as keys for the other arrays when you generate them. Drop the emails array. Use `array_keys()` with the names or websites array to get the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets join all three arrays first, to create a clean and DRY code:

```
$arrays = array(&$emails, &$names, &$websites);
//Notice that I used the variables' references so I can modify them directly.
```

And now, lets use array_unique in every array variable.

```
foreach ($arrays as $id => $array)
{
    $arrays[$id] = array_unique($array);
}
```

Your approach (remove values from the names and websites arrays using the non-unique values of the email arrays) is unnecessary. By looking at the arrays you provided, you can simply use the array_unique function in every array, as I did above.

Also, it is a best practice to have an user data in the same array. **example:**

```
$user = array(
    "name"    => "John Doe",
    "email"   => "John@example.com",
    "website" => "example.com"
);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks a million. It clears out the duplicates but it still comes in groups of three arrays... How can I make a new array like the $user you are showing?

Comment: If you're getting that data from a database, it should be together in a single multidimensional array. There are no 100% efficient methods to associate those arrays, because there are no common identifiers inside them. You could try to match the values using regular expression, but that's not a good practice and may not work every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = array('Blabla Company','Plumber','Lawyer','Plumber','Foo');
$site = array('Blabla.com','Plumber.com','Lawyer.com','','foo.com');
$email = array('info@Blabla.com','info@Plumber.com','info@Lawyer.com','info@Plumber.com','foo@bar.com');

$email = array_unique($email);
$name = array_intersect_key($name, $email);
$site = array_intersect_key($site, $email);

var_dump($email, $name, $site);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "info@Blabla.com"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "info@Plumber.com"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "info@Lawyer.com"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "foo@bar.com"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Blabla Company"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Plumber"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Lawyer"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "Foo"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Blabla.com"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Plumber.com"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Lawyer.com"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "foo.com"
}
```